# Calculate P value from Z value

Tags: probability, statistics

My data consists of values for 192 countries. I want to calculate the outlier value. For this I first calculated the z values for each using the formula for Z scores. Now I want to calculate the P values for the same. How can I calculate it ?

Comment: Are you sure your data is normally distributed or at least approximately normal? Also this may be a good source in ways to find outliers (http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/eda35h.htm)

Comment: in terms of finding p values, you can derive those from a z table (http://www.rochester.edu/college/psc/clarke/201/ztable2.jpg) or there functions for these on r (pnorm(z,0,1)) and excel =NORMDIST(z,0,1,TRUE)). Note you will need to manipulate these formulas to get actual z score. For example if you want $P(-z<Z<z)=P(Z<z)-P(Z<-z)$

Answer (score 0):

Just calculate the two-sided probability of a standard normal variable being at least $z_i$ standard deviations from the mean (i.e., $2(1-\Phi(z_i)$)